# UITableViewCell - don't remove and recycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with some cells, containing some UITextField's.
It's some very small cells and they do consume a lot of memory.

My problem is, that when you scroll, the cell will be unset for memory reasons, which is good - if you have a enormous UITableView.

My UITableView is only up to 10-15 cells, and it contains, as said, some textfields. These textfields are written by the user itself. But when the user scrolls, the values disappear, because the cell is unset.

I could make a NSMutableDictionary to store the data, but it will be overkill for this small job. Do you have a good hack to fix this issue, so the values don't disappear on scroll?

Comment: Do it the right way.  Use an NSMutableArray as your main data store (one element per row) and put either a custom object or an NSMutableDictionary in each valid element.  It's much simpler to do this in a uniform fashion rather than trying to juggle a bunch of different values.

Comment: @HotLicks please put that as an answer before this all goes horribly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all means you need to store the information outside of the cells, preferably in an NSArray in your controller or some other structure. The other alternative is to disable recycling by either giving each cell a different identifier or creating them preemptively, saving in an array, and returning them instead of dequeuing, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Yes, Indeed. It's for the best to reuse the UITableViewCell. I just think it's going to be a mess to cache all the cells in a NSArray and to update them, whenever one of the three UITextFields is updated within the single UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the right way. Use an NSMutableArray as your main data store (one element per row) and put either a custom object or an NSMutableDictionary in each valid element. It's much simpler to do this in a uniform fashion rather than trying to juggle a bunch of different values.

Comment: How would you do that? EDIT: When updating one single field in a arbitrary UITableViewCell

Comment: Update your data store and call `reloadData` on the view when you change anything.  If you want to be uber-efficient you can call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` and specify the one row to reload.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the cells in an array so they won't be freed when scrolled off the screen.

By adding the cells into an array, their reference counts will increase by 1.

Comment: The table view reuses cells when they go off the screen. Their retain count has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @jrturton You do not have to reuse cells. In this case, using an array   of cells might be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, but just adding the cells to an array won't prevent cell reuse, as your answer implies